# Input form lower text getting cut off on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have made landing page using `bootstrap-3` which i have tested for iphone devices,android devices. When i check for mobile device size for `360px` to `640px`, when i enter text in input fields lower texts are getting cut off. I have have refereed links and followed increasing or decreasing `line-height` and `font size` `padding` etc. Still it don't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line height does the trick. I set Line height with css class as `.input-height{line-height: 20}`to input tags only.Thanks.